# Is there a way to "Reset the bounding box" in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, bounding-box

Is there a way to "Reset the bounding box" in Adobe InDesign, like in Adobe Illustrator?

*This is a very important feature in here because sometimes rotated objects need get a linear-basic space, mostly when they're in-line.

Any script would be appreciated! ;)

Comment: I don't use InDesign everyday anymore, but I assume you might use an "Object Style" and apply it to the element to reset its style.

Comment: Thanks but this matter have no concerns to object styles. It's a transformation property.

Comment: I don't believe there is. InDesign stores object transformations, or alway has, better than AI. Ai is just recently catching up.

Answer (score 1):

A script could definitely do the job.
However, here's a workaround you might find useful:

Create a smaller object that you place on top of your original object.
Use the eyedropper tool in order to apply original object's aspect to your small element.

Select both and use pathfinder to merge them.
Here you go:

[image]

**Edit:** Here's another tweak:
You can also fake the bounding box using the multi-state feature.

Open Window > Interactive > Object States panel.
Select your object, and click on "new state".

If you have lots of anchored object, you can click on the "select next object" icon in your control panel.

See example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already used this trick. but it's a pain! mostly when a lot of objects are in paragraph and in-lined! then i have to cut them out of text, do the trick on 'em and place them back in!

Comment: I rather use a script though.

Comment: @Roozbeh E I have no time for developing such a free script right now (but you still can ask in the indesign official scripting forum https://forums.adobe.com/community/indesign/indesign_scripting But I have edited my answer with another workaround that you may find useful to manage anchored objects...

Comment: Appreciate it Vinny, didn't expect you to do so. but really nice of you to say. I submit my request there too. ;)